# Are PHP 4 Programs Compatible with PHP 5?

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to run a PHP 4 file in Apache/2.2.11?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have PHP4 installed, sure, it should run.  You shouldn't though, for many reasons.

If it is a really simple script, it may 'just work', but I doubt it.  You can check the [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php) document for some details.

Comment: Because of backwards compatibility you are able to run php4 code on any php5 enabled server and then it's just a matter of fixing unsupported features following Cylindric's link.

Comment: Indeed.  Pretty much depends on the application.  Anything non-trivial will probably have all sorts of sneaky problems.